# holotoolkit2017: Cannot find the HandsManager and GestureManager scripts

Tags: hololens

I added in the [unity2017.1 holotoolkit2017](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity), but I can't find *HandsManager* and *GesturesManager* scripts.

I tried to include the scripts according to the official tutorial, but the error persists.

Comment: I included a link to the project and improved the formatting of the question. I also attempted to make it clearer.

Comment: What tutorial are you using, how did you try including the scripts?

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search revealed that [version v1.2017.1.0](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/commit/f356c58b5045370c734d7ff5a27343af2208f2c4) moved parts of these two scripts:

> GestureManager.cs moved hand related interactions into HandsManager.cs

Their current location is

```
 Assets/HoloToolkit/Input/Scripts/
```

Hope this is of some help.